# Event date and time not select in datepiker less then server time

Tags: php, mysql

1. User careate feture event using bootstrep datepiker
2. User select date and time greter then currant time
   4.If user select date Event time is 04-09-14 11:55AM and server time is 04-09-14 11:60AM
   after not valid date for create event.

   I am Using this code.

   ```
       $event_time =htmlentities($_REQUEST['date_piker']) ;
       $server_time    = htmlentities( date('m-d-y h:iA')) ;
       echo 'Event time:-&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $event_time.'</br>';
       echo 'Server Time:-'. $server_time;


       if($event_time < $server_time)
       {
           echo 'Date and time is invalid';
       }
       else
       {
          echo 'Date and time is valid'; 
       }
   ```

   But It is not working. i need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$event = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y h:iA', '04-09-14 11:55AM');
$server = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y h:iA', '04-09-14 11:00AM');

if($event < $server){
    echo 'Date and time is invalid';
}else{
    echo 'Date and time is valid'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why u didnt use timestamps? like this

```
<?php

$event_time = htmlentities($_REQUEST['date_piker']);
$eventTimeTimestamp = strtotime($event_time);
$serverTimeTimestamp = time();
$server_time = htmlentities(date('m-d-y h:iA', $serverTimeTimestamp));
echo 'Event time:-&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $event_time . '</br>';
echo 'Server Time:-' . $server_time;

if ($eventTimeTimestamp < $serverTimeTimestamp) {
    echo 'Date and time is invalid';
} else {
    echo 'Date and time is valid';
}
```